# Style identification – landscape graphics using single monochrome layers of the same tone

Tags: style-identification, art

I really enjoy these images, I know the second one is from a game, I'm just hoping someone can tell me what these types of art might be categorized as so I could get more into them. Thanks.

[image: City Skyline]

[image: Fire Tower]

Sources of Images [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRumE.png)](http://alpha.wallhaven.cc/wallpaper/41041), [[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jASk.jpg)](http://alpha.wallhaven.cc/wallpaper/3590)

Comment: Do you know which game that second image is from? Looks interesting!

Comment: @DA01 Yeah, they have an awesome website for it: http://www.firewatchgame.com/

Comment: "silhouette vector landscape" or "minimalist vector landscape" as search terms turns up some similar stuff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second image is from the game Firewatch, which was visually developed by artist Olly Moss, of Mondo poster fame. http://ollymoss.com/

This is a form of minimalism. It's marked by strong, geometric shapes and pared-down design elements. Often, a single dominant image stands alone to deliver a powerful message.

In Moss' work, bold, layered colors create a sense of depth and distance. The farther in the distance objects are, the more they fade into simple colors and fewer details.

Another classic example of this style is work by the designer Saul Bass.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It gave me new insight as to why I like these images, and helped me find similar examples.

Comment: I love Saul Bass but am not familiar with this style in his work? Any good examples?

Answer (score 3):

A traditional method which shares features of those images is **wood block printing**.

Obviously, this is a method rather than a style, but considering the large block forms of single colors, this method is probably the closest.

Serigraphs (silk screen) share some features but they are more easily able to use gradients and shading.

[image: wood block prints: a screen capture from an image search]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any particular name for these. They are a mix of various styles and techniques:

- monochromatic
- flat/vector based
- layered to emulate distance

Answer (score -1):

these are called 2D Silhouette Landscape's

Comment: Can you please elaborate and possibly add some references/images?